# Django file upload progress get cache returns None

Tags: django, caching, file-upload, progress

Django file upload progress process json request getting null response

***view.py***

```
def upload_progress(request):
    """
    A view to report back on upload progress.
    Return JSON object with information about the progress of an upload.

    Copied from:
    http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/678/

    See upload.py for file upload handler.
    """
    #import ipdb
    #ipdb.set_trace()
    progress_id = ''
    if 'X-Progress-ID' in request.GET:
        progress_id = request.GET['X-Progress-ID']
    elif 'X-Progress-ID' in request.META:
        progress_id = request.META['X-Progress-ID']
    if progress_id:
        from django.utils import simplejson
        cache_key = "%s_%s" % (request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'], progress_id)
        data = cache.get(cache_key)


        return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(data))
```

***UploadProgressCachedHandler.py***

```
    from django.core.files.uploadhandler import FileUploadHandler
    from django.core.cache import cache

    class UploadProgressCachedHandler(FileUploadHandler):
        """
        Tracks progress for file uploads.
        The http post request must contain a header or query parameter, 'X-Progress-ID'
        which should contain a unique string to identify the upload to be tracked.

        Copied from:
        http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/678/

        See views.py for upload_progress function...
        """

        def __init__(self, request=None):
            super(UploadProgressCachedHandler, self).__init__(request)
            self.progress_id = None
            self.cache_key = None

        def handle_raw_input(self, input_data, META, content_length, boundary, encoding=None):
            self.content_length = content_length
            if 'X-Progress-ID' in self.request.GET :
                self.progress_id = self.request.GET['X-Progress-ID']
            elif 'X-Progress-ID' in self.request.META:
                self.progress_id = self.request.META['X-Progress-ID']
            if self.progress_id:
                self.cache_key = "%s_%s" % (self.request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'], self.progress_id )
                cache.set(self.cache_key, {
                    'length': self.content_length,
                    'uploaded' : 0
                })

        def new_file(self, field_name, file_name, content_type, content_length, charset=None):
            pass

        def receive_data_chunk(self, raw_data, start):
            if self.cache_key:
                data = cache.get(self.cache_key)
                data['uploaded'] += self.chunk_size
                cache.set(self.cache_key, data)
                #cache.set(self.cache_key, 5000)
            return raw_data

        def file_complete(self, file_size):
            pass

        def upload_complete(self):
            if self.cache_key:
                cache.delete(self.cache_key)
```

Iam setting cache with uploadProgressCacheHandler. But when tries to retrieve via json request .The `data` returning `None` object.'cache_key' is generating correctly.

Please help.

Comment: same problem.. cache returns null

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are trying to make the JSON request when the flow already has reached `upload_complete`. At that point `cache_key` has been deleted from cache (that's why it is empty).

Are you using the Django development server? I think this built-in server only allows to handle one request at time, which in your situation means that first the upload is completed and following the JSON request is processed. You can try with another server (ex: Apache) able to handle multiple requests.

Comment: I've like the same Code but if I tried on my Apache Server. I still get a None. Do you know why this is? Is it possible that I've to configure also Apache for this?

Comment: I have the same problem. I'm using local memory caching, the default setting, and Django 1.5 with Apache 2.2 using mod_wsgi. The cache has no data.